# How to make a file with docker env

Tags: docker

I tried so many things, and I've searched google for hours but my Dockerfile I'm doing some tests with doesn't work

```
From debian:stretch

ENV GREETING=Hello \
NAME=World

RUN echo $GREETING > greeting.json 
RUN cat greeting.json
```

The purpose of this is that I'm trying to pass a key to a json file that my program will read

```
FROM node:current

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV token = '{"token": "'$KEY'"}'

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

RUN echo $token > key.json
RUN cat key.json

CMD [ "npm", "a" ]

COPY . .
```

This is the Dockerfile I'll be using in the end and I hope running

> docker run --env KEY="" --name bot

will work. The reason why I put the key variable inside the token variable is cause I wasn't sure if I could concat inside the echo command

If there's a more optimal way feedback is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

*The purpose of this is that I'm trying to pass a key to a json file that my program will read*

Why does your program reads keys from file? It can read from environment variable.

See [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and [process.env](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/process.html#process_process_env).

```js
require('dotenv').config()

// now your token is available
const token = process.env.TOKEN;
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how all this deployment and production works and I'm just playing around to get a feel for it. So the intention is to pass the key through env in docker run, I wanted to do this because I don't keep key in the repo but I want to run the program and it can't find the key. I'm looking dot env and says to keep the .env in a different repo?

Comment: @Nik3348 well ok, honestly, I think you need to read more about some specific topics before continue your work. I'd recommend learn more about environment variables.
Very briefly - in your case environment variables can be defined in `Dockerfile`, as well as in separate `.env` file.
But, seriously, just read more about it. It'll help.

Comment: Yea its just some side projects I'm doing, have any good reads by any chance? Thanks for your input

Comment: google `environment variables node js`, there're plenty of good articles

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Thank you I managed to pass the env variable through docker into my program with the process.env,

```
docker run --env KEY="key"
```

can be read like

```
const KEY = process.env.KEY;
```